# Add multiple form entries to List<T> ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I currently have a form in ASP.NET Core that I'm needing to store the Form data somehow before submitting all the data at once to the database. Submitting the data per addition to the `entries` renders that `entry` as "incomplete" and may cause issues internally. I've decided that using `List<T>` might accomplish my goal. I have written the C# portion that will add my form `entries`, run my checks and add them to my database as needed. However, what I have written currently only works if entries are entered one at a time so I am trying to create a more dynamic solution to allow multiple entries to be stored prior to submitting to the database.

My test model:

```cs
public class TestModel
{
    public int Id { get; set;}
    
    [Display(Name = "Account Number")]
    public string AccountNumber { get; set;}
    
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 3)]
    [RegularExpression(@"^[a-zA-Z0-9""/'\s-]*$")]
    [Display(Name = "Account Description")]
    public string AccountDescription { get; set; }
    
    [Display(Name = "Post Date")]
    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    public DateTime PostDate { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
    
    // This is definitely not a good place to put this.
    //  Tried having this here to have it transfer back and forth between View and Controller
    public List<TestModel> TicketList { get; set; } = new List<TestModel>();
}
```

My test View:

```aspnet
@model TestModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Test Form";
    Layout = "_Layout";
}

<h1>@ViewData["Title"]</h1>

<hr/>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="Create">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="hidden" asp-for="AccountNumber" id="AccountNumber" value="" />
                <input type="hidden" asp-for="AccountDescription" id="AccountDescription" value="" />
            </div>
            
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label">Account</label>
                <select id="AccountInfo" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.AccountNumber" onchange="handleAccountDropDownChange('')">
                    <option value="">--Select Account--</option>
                </select>
                <span asp-validation-for="AccountNumber" class="text-danger" />
            </div>
            
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label"></label>
                <input id="PostDate" asp-for="PostDate" class="form-control" value="@DateTime.Now" />
                <span asp-validation-for="PostDate" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            
            <div class="form-group">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Create" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <button id="AddFormEntry" type="button" class="btn btn-primary\">Add To Group Entry</button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
    
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

My test Controller:

```cs
[Area("Test")]
public class TestEntriesController : Controller
{
    private readonly TestContext _context;

    // List to store each entry to be added into the context
    List<TestFinalModel> entryList = new List<TestFinalModel>();

    // Test Entry Submission model to hold information
    TestModel testSubmission = new TestModel();

    public TestEntriesController(TestEntriesContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    // GET: Test/TestEntries/Create
    public IActionResult Create()
    {
        // Populate ViewBag for dropdown list
        PopulateAccountInfoDropdownList();
        
        return View();
    }

    // POST: Test/TestEntries/Create
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("AccountNumber, AccountDescription, PostDate")] TestModel entrySubmission)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // Create new instance of tools and pass current context
            TestEntriesTools tools = new TestEntriesTools(_context);

            // Run check on entry Posting descriptions and apply change if needed
            entrySubmission = tools.CheckEntryDescription(entrySubmission);

            // Add new entry to submission
            testSubmission.entryList.Add(entrySubmission);

            foreach (var entry in testSubmission.entryList)
            {
                // Add entry submission data to entryList
                tools.CreateTestEntryList(User, entry, entryList);
            }            

            foreach (TestFinalModel item in entryList)
            {
                item.Id = 0;
                _context.Add(item);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }

            // Clear out list after entrys have been added to the database
            testSubmission.entryList.Clear();
            entryList.Clear();
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }


        PopulateAccountInfoDropdownList();
        return View(testSubmission);
    }

    [HttpPost("/Test/TestEntries/Controller/AddToGroupEntry")]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public void AddToGroupEntry(string accountNumber, string accountDescription, DateTime postDate)
    {
        TestModel newSubmission = new TestModel();

        newSubmission.AccountNumber = accountNumber;
        newSubmission.AccountDescription = accountDescription;
        newSubmission.PostDate = postDate;
        
        testSubmission.entryList.Add(newSubmission);
    }
}
```

I'm currently sending my data and firing off my `AddToGroupEntry()` method using an AJAX request with a `click` event on my `#AddFormEntry` button. When I debug step-through the process, I see everything is working as intended, entries are getting added, all is good. However, I realize that it is leaving the Scope of the controller to return back to my View to allow for more entries. This causes my global variables to no longer matter, as they don't hold their values due to leaving Scope.

My question:

How can I store multiple form entries in a `List<T>` without submitting the changes to my database?

I have found that I can send my data via `ViewBag[]` to my `View`, however I'm not certain how I would get it back to my `Controller` or move the data back and forth as needed.

Any help is appreciated! I've still learning the ropes of ASP.NET Core and have only created C# WinForms in the passed. *Any* help or advice on what I could do better is always appreciated!

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You could store temporary data in a file such as a `.txt` or a `.xml` instead of using a `List<T>`. And just read from the file when you want to add to the DB

Comment: You could store the entities using Session state.  The Session state is an ASP.NET Core scenario for storage of user data while the user browses a web app. Session state uses a store maintained by the app to persist data across requests from a client. More detail information about configure and use Session state, see [Session state](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-5.0#session-state). Since you want to store list of objects, you still need to add SessionExtensions. Then, when you want to insert data into database, get them from session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are thinking about it the wrong way.

MVC controllers try to be stateless. Which means you cannot store any information in the controller variables and expect it to be there next time when you go back-and-forth from your view to the controller.

This is because every time you hit a controller action (from the view) you get a new controller. Then when you go back to the view, the controller is destroyed.

So to temporarily save some variables you should store them somewhere else. Like on the filesystem, in a database.

In your case maybe it is best to refactor the code so that you store the entries in a javascript array before sending them all together to the server for processing.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! I been researching a JavaScript solution as well. However, I'm still super new to Javascript. Would be able to provide a POC with the JavaScript solution?

Comment: Can you share ur javascript you have so far?

Comment: I've actually now decided to go ahead and go the database route. I had wanted to avoid it due to some self-fabricated doubts about it but looks like I was able to prove that I could do it! Thank you for your answer and explanation of how Views work with their Controllers!